# Visual Studio Code: could not find an installed version of pre-commit

Tags: visual-studio-code, pre-commit

I need to run pre-commit tests on my project and so I've downloaded and insalled the following extension for VSCode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarkLarah.pre-commit-vscode

It says to simply "Type pre-commit run into the VSCode command bar", which gives me the following error after selecting a test:
[Could not find an installed version of pre-commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF1lx.png)

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

The extension `pre-commit-vscode` looks for `pre-commit` in following paths as of now:

```
    venv/bin/pre-commit
    virtualenv_run/bin/pre-commit
    virtualenv/bin/pre-commit
```

Reference: https://github.com/magicmark/pre-commit-vscode/blob/68b0f656d23520e6639a270c8d024da81b7cd509/src/index.js#L40

So as long as we can install a binary in those paths, it will work.

Author has a [TODO](https://github.com/magicmark/pre-commit-vscode/blob/68b0f656d23520e6639a270c8d024da81b7cd509/src/index.js#L34) apparently to look for the binary in $PATH. Until then, you got to use the above workaround.